# How to change state of a sibiling, if I click on a component?

Tags: reactjs

I have three components that render a list of available timeslots.

If I click on a timeslot on the list of component1, it gets selected, now, If a sibiling component, let's call it component2, also has a timeslot that matches the one that had been clicked on component1, I want the one in component2 to be greyed out.

How can I do this?

The components that render the lists of available timeslots are called CompanyPanel:

```
export default class CompanyPanel extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      selectedTime: 'None',
      times: this.props.times,
    }

    this.chooseTime = this.chooseTime.bind(this)
    this.deleteTime = this.deleteTime.bind(this)

  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.chooseTime(this.state.selectedTime)
  }

  deleteTime (time) {
    this.setState( ({times}) => ({
      times: [...this.state.times].filter( t => t !== time),
    }))    
  }

  chooseTime (selectedTime) {
    this.setState({
      selectedTime,
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { selectedTime, times } = this.state

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="flex-auto pa3">
          <div className="ba mv2">
            <p className="tc pa2 dib bg-near-white">{this.props.name}</p>
          </div>
          <div className="ba mv2">
            <p className="tc pa2 dib bg-red white">{selectedTime}</p>
          </div>
          <div className="ba mv2">
            {times.map((time, i) => (
              <div key={i} className="bg-green">
                <span className="pa2 red pointer ma2 bg-white" onClick={() => this.deleteTime(time)}>X</span>
                <p onClick={() => this.chooseTime(time.dateUTCString)} className="tc pa2 dib bg-yellow">{time.dateUTCString}</p>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

And those CompanyPanel components are being wrapper by a parent component called CompaniesDashboard:

```
export default class CompaniesDashboard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      error: null,
      data,
    }

    this.isLoading = this.isLoading.bind(this)
  }

  isLoading() {
    return this.state.posts === null && this.state.error === null
  }

  render() {
    const { data, error } = this.state

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {this.isLoading() && <p>LOADING</p>}
        {error && <p>{error}</p>}

        <div className="flex">
          {data && data.map((company, i) => (
            <CompanyPanel key={i} times={company.times} name={company.name} />
          ))}
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

I think i need to somehow to set a state in the parent, when the `chooseTime` method is clicked inside if the CompanyPanel component. But not sure how to do it.

Comment: Your instinct is correct. The parent component should likely have a state property that tracks what's selected and passes that information down to the children. Then, the children can use that information to grey things out as needed.

Comment: thx, do you have any exampe on how that looks?

Comment: Well, you already have state in the parent element, so you could add a key `selectedCompanyTime` and then an `updateSelectedCompanyTime` method that changes state. Then pass both of those down to the children.